# Combine lists into a data.table when length of list elements differs

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a 3 objects that I wish to combine into a `data.table`, one vector of length 1 ('id'), and two lists:

```
id = "ID 1"
scores = list(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,2), c(0,0,3,2,1), c(2,2,2), c(2,2,2))
age = list(c(30,30,31), c(52,42,33), NA, c(54,62,11), c(65,66,12))
```

Note that the 3rd element in 'scores' has 5 values, while the corresponding element in 'age' contains just a single `NA`.

I want to combine these three objects row-wise by doing

```
data.table(id = id, scores = unlist(scores), age = unlist(age))
```

Obviously this errors due to the different length of the two unlisted lists:

> In as.data.table.list(x, keep.rownames = keep.rownames, check.names =
> check.names,  :   Item 3 has 13 rows but longest item has 17; recycled
> with remainder.

I ultimately want

```
      id scores age
 1: ID 1      1  30
 2: ID 1      2  30
 3: ID 1      3  31
 4: ID 1      2  52
 5: ID 1      3  42
 6: ID 1      2  33
 7: ID 1      0  NA
 8: ID 1      0  NA
 9: ID 1      3  NA
10: ID 1      2  NA
11: ID 1      1  NA
12: ID 1      2  54
13: ID 1      2  62
14: ID 1      2  11
15: ID 1      2  65
16: ID 1      2  66
17: ID 1      2  12
```

That is, the single `NA` in the third element of 'age' is repeated 5 times, to obtain the same length as the corresponding third element in 'scores'.
How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a helper function using `mapply()` that expands length-1 `NA`s to the length of the corresponding element in the other list:

```
library(data.table)

expand_na <- function(x, y) {
  mapply(
    \(x, y) if (length(x) == 1 && is.na(x)) rep(x, length(y)) else x,
    x,
    y
  )
}

data.table(
  id = id,
  scores = unlist(scores),
  age = unlist(expand_na(age, scores))
)
```

```
     id scores age
 1: ID 1      1  30
 2: ID 1      2  30
 3: ID 1      3  31
 4: ID 1      2  52
 5: ID 1      3  42
 6: ID 1      2  33
 7: ID 1      0  NA
 8: ID 1      0  NA
 9: ID 1      3  NA
10: ID 1      2  NA
11: ID 1      1  NA
12: ID 1      2  54
13: ID 1      2  62
14: ID 1      2  11
15: ID 1      2  65
16: ID 1      2  66
17: ID 1      2  12
```

Comment: what is the backslash for in front of `(x,y)`? thanks!

Comment: That’s shorthand for an anonymous function — it’s equivalent to `function(x, y)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also wrap your own approach with `lapply` and `rbindlist` to return your desired output.

```r
library(data.table)

rbindlist(lapply(seq_along(scores), \(x) {
  data.table(id=id, scores=unlist(scores[x]), age=unlist(age[x]))
}))

#     id scores age
# 1: ID 1      1  30
# 2: ID 1      2  30
# 3: ID 1      3  31
# 4: ID 1      2  52
# 5: ID 1      3  42
# 6: ID 1      2  33
# 7: ID 1      0  NA
# 8: ID 1      0  NA
# 9: ID 1      3  NA
#10: ID 1      2  NA
#11: ID 1      1  NA
#12: ID 1      2  54
#13: ID 1      2  62
#14: ID 1      2  11
#15: ID 1      2  65
#16: ID 1      2  66
#17: ID 1      2  12
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `unnest`, which automatically does the replication if there is a single NA

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(id, scores, age) %>% 
  unnest(where(is.list))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 17 × 3
   id    scores   age
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 ID 1       1    30
 2 ID 1       2    30
 3 ID 1       3    31
 4 ID 1       2    52
 5 ID 1       3    42
 6 ID 1       2    33
 7 ID 1       0    NA
 8 ID 1       0    NA
 9 ID 1       3    NA
10 ID 1       2    NA
11 ID 1       1    NA
12 ID 1       2    54
13 ID 1       2    62
14 ID 1       2    11
15 ID 1       2    65
16 ID 1       2    66
17 ID 1       2    12
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option with `Map`

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  Map(cbind, list(data.frame(id)), scores = scores, age = age)
)
```

which gives

```
     id scores age
1  ID 1      1  30
2  ID 1      2  30
3  ID 1      3  31
4  ID 1      2  52
5  ID 1      3  42
6  ID 1      2  33
7  ID 1      0  NA
8  ID 1      0  NA
9  ID 1      3  NA
10 ID 1      2  NA
11 ID 1      1  NA
12 ID 1      2  54
13 ID 1      2  62
14 ID 1      2  11
15 ID 1      2  65
16 ID 1      2  66
17 ID 1      2  12
```

---

If you want to finally obtain a `data.table` object, you can try

```
rbindlist(
  Map(
    cbind,
    list(data.table(id)),
    scores = scores,
    age = age
  )
)
```

which gives

```
      id scores age
 1: ID 1      1  30
 2: ID 1      2  30
 3: ID 1      3  31
 4: ID 1      2  52
 5: ID 1      3  42
 6: ID 1      2  33
 7: ID 1      0  NA
 8: ID 1      0  NA
 9: ID 1      3  NA
10: ID 1      2  NA
11: ID 1      1  NA
12: ID 1      2  54
13: ID 1      2  62
14: ID 1      2  11
15: ID 1      2  65
16: ID 1      2  66
17: ID 1      2  12
```